# Bootstrap page not scrollable

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I have a HTML page that has a list

```
<div class="list-group content" id="feed_list" style="background-color:#EAEBED;padding:2%;">
  <button type="button" class="list-group-item" onclick="storeValue('5264377385058304','0')"><span>NITK Alumni Book </span><span style="float:right;">News Post<br>Posted on 2015-12-18</span></button>
  <button type="button" class="list-group-item" onclick="storeValue('5550988605784064','1')"><span>Power Talks</span><span style="float:right;">Start Date : 18-12-2015<br>Start Time : 3:00 PM</span></button>
  <button type="button" class="list-group-item" onclick="storeValue('5303272608890880','1')"><span>Entrepreneurship Track</span><span style="float:right;">Start Date : 19-12-2015<br>Start Time : 09:00 AM</span></button>
  <button type="button" class="list-group-item" onclick="storeValue('5311098710392832','1')"><span>Startups Track</span><span style="float:right;">Start Date : 19-12-2015<br>Start Time : 11:15 AM</span></button>
  <button type="button" class="list-group-item" onclick="storeValue('6640800855228416','1')"><span>Skill India Track</span><span style="float:right;">Start Date : 19-12-2015<br>Start Time : 11:15 AM</span></button>
  <button type="button" class="list-group-item" onclick="storeValue('6640800855228416','1')"><span>Skill India Track</span><span style="float:right;">Start Date : 19-12-2015<br>Start Time : 11:15 AM</span></button>
</div>
```

However, the page is not scrollable and one of the butons is hidden. How do I fix this?  The page and necessary files can be found [here](http://1drv.ms/1S6Uc3g)

Comment: Do you want to scroll horizontal or vertical?

Comment: @Radavel oops.. vertical.. The list is vertical

Comment: @Radavel can we just give it enough scroll dependng on the content??

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I'have checked your codes.

Please remove `body{overflow:hidden}` in CSS and also remove `footer postion:fixed`

Like us,

```
body {
    overflow: auto;
}
footer{
  position:static;
 }
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use css for fix it:

```
.list-group{
  overflow-y: scroll;
  max-height: 500px; // You can change this value
}
```

I hope it helps you...